# Scapy show packet content after sniffing it - UnicodeEncodeError

Tags: python-3.x, scapy

I want to sniff ProfiNet Connect Messages and print them to console every time i receive them. Herefore i used the Scapy `sniff`  method. Every time a `Connect`-Frame is received the following error is displayed. The `Connect`-Message is in correct format and is visible in Wireshark. The sniff-method aborts every time such a frame is received. If i export the frame with wireshark and read the .pcap-file with scapy the frame is correctly displayed. Do you have any suggestions? I'm currently using Python 3.8.10 and scapy version 2.4.5rc1.dev205. Thanks!

UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\u0797' in position 595: ordinal not in range(256)

```
def update_connect_load(pkt): 
    pkt.show2() 

def stopFilter(x):
    return False

sniff(
    filter=f"ether src {mac_address}",
    store=0,
    count=-1,
    prn=update_connect_load,
    iface=iface,
    stop_filter=stopFilter,
)`
```

Tried encoding the paket in the prn-function, but that didn't work. Also tried parsing the packet with DceRpc() but that also didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Just update the Python Version to 3.9 and everything works!